# Can Vulkan Be Used To Acess The Framebuffer?

Tags: vulkan

I'm interested in being able to access the [frambuffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framebuffer) using Vulkan. I want to be able to write a program that captures my screen contents. Is this something Vulkan is capable of?

I'm new to graphics programming. I started [this](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Introduction) Vulkan tutorial last night. Everything seems to be talking about creating geometry. I have no problem learning the geometry if it'll help me understand what I'm trying to do better, but I want to make sure I'll actually be able to do that before continuing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan is a graphics rendering API. While it has mechanisms to draw to some part of the screen(s), it can only render to those parts of the screen(s) it has been given the right to access. This typically means the part of the screen(s) bounded by some window, though there are implementations that allow for rendering directly to the display.

But even with them, you would be overwriting the display; reading from such an image isn't required to allow you to access someone else's data.

If you just want to screen-shot your desktop, you should use an OS-specific mechanism for that.

Comment: Follow up: [RFB's Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RFB_protocol) says it works on all windowing systems due to using the framebuffer. I took that to mean they directly access it. Perhaps they us OS mechanisms as you suggested to me though. Do you happen to know what they do? Or should I redirect this question elsewhere?

Comment: "The framebuffer" means different things in different contexts. A Vulkan framebuffer is not the same as the operating/windowing system's framebuffer (unless you're writing an app that runs full-screen, but it sounds like you want to capture the contents of *other* apps). So yes, you need to look elsewhere -- I'm not sure where, but it isn't Vulkan or another 3D rendering API (D3D, OpenGL, etc.), and it'll be OS-specific.